# application email service, send identical emails from public api and website

Tags: java, php, api, email

in a student project we are currently developing a website which service is also accessibly via native Android and Windows Phone Apps.
The mobile apps access the service through a public RESTful API written in JAVA which is running on the same server as the website. The website is written in PHP and independent from the API, but they both use the same database (MySQL).

We wanted to extend the functionality of the API and allow registration for the service in the mobile apps.
The problem is that the user receives an email with a confirmation link as soon as he registers for the service.

What is the best approach to ensure that the emails sent by the API are identical to the ones sent by the website?
The easiest way we figured out doing this would be just using the same templates for both, website and API, but in that case we need to manually keep those templates in sync.

Is there a better way than the one above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates need not be in flat file model in each environment. You can store it at one place but should be read by a common `intra-web-api` say local RPC.

I.e. Write a script in current website environment that returns either a template or duly filled in as the requirement case may be.

And the same API should be called from both web-site php scripts and from java API.

This process will not alter the output in both the environments. The output would always be the same when on a later date you change the template.